# How to reproject a noaa bsb nautical chart?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal

I have some nautical charts in .BSB format. GDAL can read bsb and I successfully imported them to qgis. But I can't figure out what is the coordinate system they use.
Does anyone has some experience with .bsb ?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am having the same issue in qGIS 3.10. I import the .kap file but there's no CRS associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

In the FME Readers and Writers Manual we note that the coordinate system for BSB is always what we call LL-WGS84. It seems that EPSG:6326 is the equivalent.